# OAS 3 which behavior for empty Content-Type in request?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Using OAS 3 to describe my API, I have for specific call following requestBody defined

```
requestBody:
  content:
    application/json:
      ...
```

Searching in https://swagger.io/specification I found nothing about behavior if user doesn't inquire `Content-Type` or inquire it badly (in my case, we only have `application/json` and we simulate Content-Type as `application/xml`) in request. An error must be returned ? The call definition must not be checked ?

Comment: you can define the responses for your OAS3 service, refer https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/#status-codes

And, using above reference you can have a 415 status code response defined for the request that is unsupported (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415)